# How to replace all instances of a word/string in an array with another word/string

Tags: arrays, loops

I have an array that contains some formatted price totals and is being printed, it is basically keys and values.

The array is called $info['order_total']

How can I loop through all the values and replace all instances of the words 'Collection' & 'Delivery' with 'card charge'

Comment: You can loop and replace, with your language's instruments...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming php:

```
for ($info['order_total'] as $key=>$value){
    if ($value == 'Collection' || $value == 'Delivery'){
        $info[$key] = 'card charge';
    }
}
```

or similarly:

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($info['order_total'];$i++)){
    if ($info['order_total'][$i] == 'Collection' ||
        $info['order_total'][$i] == 'Delivery'){
        $info['order_total'][$i] = 'card charge';
    }
}
```